# Remove duplicates from list but keep by color preference

Tags: python

I have a list that contains duplicates like this..

```
"id","name","type","price","color"
"23","item1","t-shirt","37","red"
"56","item66","jumper","3","yellow"
"366","item7","jumper","55","yellow"
"366","item7","jumper","55","red"
"745","item 9","t-shirt","45","green"
"3245","item 12","t-shirt","67","red"
"3245","item 12","t-shirt","67","purple"
"654","item 88","jumper","66","blue"
"2","item 99","jumper","77","purple"
"2","item 99","jumper","77","green"
```

I want to remove the duplicates but keep the one by order or color prefence by this table..

```
1 - Red
2 - Purple
3 - Blue
4 - Green
5 - Yellow
```

So the final list would look like this..

```
"id","name","type","price","color"
"23","item1","t-shirt","37","red"
"56","item66","jumper","3","yellow"
"366","item7","jumper","55","red"
"745","item 9","t-shirt","45","green"
"3245","item 12","t-shirt","67","red"
"654","item 88","jumper","66","blue"
"2","item 99","jumper","77","purple"
```

What is my best approach? Would sorting them by color prefernce first and then removing duplicates be a workable solution? If so, does anybody have an example of something similar being achieved? I am not sure how to sort by order of preferenc.

Comment: How do you define "duplicate"? Duplicate IDs? Duplicate names? Duplicate types? Duplicate price? Duplicate color? There is no single line which is exactly duplicate with respect to all properties.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove the duplicates"?  There is only one id 366 if the list with "remove duplicates"  but there are two rows in the original list and they are not identical.   Which one should be kept?

Comment: Keep "puple"? That's not even a valid color.

Answer (score 2):

Sort the data according to the color preference and then groupby id, the first element and then get all the first elements of the group.

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [
    ["id", "name", "type", "price", "color"],
    ["23", "item1", "t-shirt", "37", "red"],
    ["56", "item66", "jumper", "3", "yellow"],
    ["366", "item7", "jumper", "55", "yellow"],
    ["366", "item7", "jumper", "55", "red"],
    ["745", "item 9", "t-shirt", "45", "green"],
    ["3245", "item 12", "t-shirt", "67", "red"],
    ["3245", "item 12", "t-shirt", "67", "purple"],
    ["654", "item 88", "jumper", "66", "blue"],
    ["2", "item 99", "jumper", "77", "purple"],
    ["2", "item 99", "jumper", "77", "green"]
]
header = data[0]
data = data[1:]
preference = {
    "red": 1,
    "purple": 2,
    "blue": 3,
    "green": 4,
    "yellow": 5
}


def key_function(element):
    color = element[-1]
    return (element[0], preference[color])


data.sort(key=key_function)
print(header)
for group, grouping in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x[0]):
    print(next(grouping))
```

OUTPUT

```
['id', 'name', 'type', 'price', 'color']
['2', 'item 99', 'jumper', '77', 'purple']
['23', 'item1', 't-shirt', '37', 'red']
['3245', 'item 12', 't-shirt', '67', 'red']
['366', 'item7', 'jumper', '55', 'red']
['56', 'item66', 'jumper', '3', 'yellow']
['654', 'item 88', 'jumper', '66', 'blue']
['745', 'item 9', 't-shirt', '45', 'green']
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the original is a list of lists (one list for each line)

convert it to a single list where each item is an id followed by a tuple ("name", "type", "price", "color")

```
    list2=[]
    for item in list1:
      x= [item[0],tuple(item[1:])]
      list2.append(x)
```

Now make a dictionary out of list 2.  This will have no duplicate keys  (id numbers) but there is no guarantee which line will be used

```
    dict1=dict(list2)
```

If we just sort the dictionary the sorting will be done by id.   So we use the key parameter of sorted.   Key is a function, normally a lambda function is used here, but a regular named function will work.   It should take one parameter, an item of the thing being sorted and return something that can be checked for order.  We specify the order a list.

```
    Order_list=["red","purple","blue","green","yellow"]



    def sort_key(x):
        check = x[1][3]   #(a color)
        key = Order_list.index(check)
        return key
```

And now we can sort our dictionary

```
    sorted(dict1, key = sort_key)
```

The return value will be a list of k:value pairs with the value of each pair a 4 tuple.